# Continuity of quadratic function

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

For each $t\in[0,T]$ let $U(t)$ be a ($n\times n$ symmetric) positive-definite matrix and suppose $U(\cdot)\in L^\infty([0,T])$. Write $L^2:=L^2([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$. Is
$$(f,g):= \int_0^Tf(t)'U(t)g(t)dt$$
a weak-continuous mapping in $L^2\times L^2$?

I tried this: if $f_n\rightharpoonup f,\ g_n\rightharpoonup g$ are nets, then
$$|(f_n,g_n)-(f,g)|\leq
|(f_n-f,g_n)|+|(f,g-g_n)|$$
but in order to conclude I need $g_n$ bounded. Too much time since I read functonal analysis haha

Comment: If $U(t)$ is a matrix the result will also be a matrix.

Comment: $f,g$ are vector valued and by $f'$ I mean the transpose